# AngularJS ChosenJS ng-disabled not working

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have a code similar to this

the select

```
<select data-placeholder="Product" class="span4 chzn-select"
    chosen="productsList" ng-model="selectedproduct"
    ng-options="product.productName for product in productsList"
    ng-change="fetchProductItems();"
    ng-disabled="lock">
</select>
```

The button that call the function

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="searchProduct();">Seach Product</button>
```

And at last the function

```
$scope.searchProduct = function() {
    $scope.lock =true;
}
```

The problem is it doesn't disable the select.

Comment: Are you using IE8? ng-disabled doesn't support IE8 and older IEs.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested your code and everything works fine, so there are 2 possible issues:

**A)** The controller somehow not connected to the view or some syntax error (check your   console window for possible errors).

**B)** might be a browser compatibility issue but I tested it on IE 10 ,chrome and FF 27.0.1 .

html:

```
<div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select data-placeholder="Product" class="span4 chzn-select"
    chosen="productsList" ng-model="selectedproduct"
    ng-options="product.productName for product in productsList"
    ng-change="fetchProductItems();"
    ng-disabled="lock">
</select>
<button class="btn" ng-click="searchProduct()">Seach Product</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.productsList=[{id:1,productName:"aa"},{id:2,productName:"bb"},{id:3,productName:"cc"}]
    $scope.searchProduct = function() {
    $scope.lock =true;
    }  
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/sJZf7/

Comment: thank you for your answer and your jsfiddle. I tried in firefox and IE and still the same. With the variable lock I am also disabling another input type text and works. Now I am checking the versions of every library I am using.

Comment: it's strange, what version of IE and FF you use?

Comment: Version of IE 11.09600.16521,version of FF 28.0. Now I realized that in the fiddle is not working the chosenjs, and I suspect that the problem is between chosenjs and angularjs. I am trying to update the fiddlejs. Thank you @alex-choroshin

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me that everything was fine but the view (which has the `ng-disabled="..."` attributes) was cached and so the attribute `ng-disabled="..."` wasn't really in the brought view.

So... delete your cache and try again.